# Twilio is sending the pin in the Body for Sandbox testing. Is this expected?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to test my API using Twilio Sandbox number. When I send an SMS "12345 Hello" where 12345 is the Pin it looks like Twilio is appending this pin to the request BODY. Is this the expected behaviour? Are we supposed to strip the pin from the body in our API? Shouldn't Twilio strip the pin and send only Hello as the Body of the sms message? Currently I get 12345 Hello as the body of the SMS message and since I am not checking for the pin the sms fails.

Comment: Hi Twilio Evangelist here. I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but anything you set in the SMS Body will be sent as the SMS Body. Twilio will not remove anything. Can you add some code? By PIN, do you mean a Twilio Account SID or Auth Token?

Comment: @xmjw When we are testing using Sandbox number we are supposed to append the Sandbox pin along with the Body of the message. Isn't it? When we do that our REST api gets the body of the sms message along with the pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is expected behaviour. The [Sandbox](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-the-twilio-sandbox-number-work) has actually been [deprecated](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sandbox), so it may be worth moving away from this for your tests.

Twilio has [Test Credentials](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/where-are-my-test-credentials) that you can use which should make things smoother. You can find out about how to use these credentials [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials).

Comment: But looks like we cannot use the Test credentials to test the receiving text part. It can be used only for sending Texts. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Okay. I see. So, if you are trying to test the code that receives an SMS from Twilio, you could just make the HTTP request directly to the SMS endpoint you have setup, using the exact parameters you need, as specified on the http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request. Effectively a mock incoming.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes.. and I am doing that. But my question was not that. My question was what should I expect in the BODY of the message when I am using the Sandbox testing. It looks like Twilio expects the pin to be added in front of the text in the BODY when sending the text message to Twilio short code. Is there anyway to bypass this?